# Can Task be started in NOT background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I need to allow task execution after main thread exits. Is it possible?
Or I should use Thread class explicitly for this purpose?

Comment: Can't you just wait for all the `Task`s you have before exiting the main thread?

Comment: @svick You are right, this is an acceptable approach...bu not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own task scheduler to schedule tasks on non-threadpool-threads... but a simpler option would probably be to start a foreground thread which just waits for the relevant tasks to complete.

(It's hard to give a code sample as you haven't shown how the tasks are started etc, but it should be fairly easy.)

Comment: Congrats on your 22222nd answer.